# Choosing numbers at random - expected value calculation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

From set $\{1,2,\ldots,49 \}$ we choose at random 6 numbers without replacing them. Let X denotes quantity of odd numbers chosen. Find $\mathbb{E}X$, how to find that? I have no idea whatsoever.

**EDIT:**: still looking for the sufficient explanation.

Comment: By symmetry, the probability that any number chosen is odd is 25/49 hence E(X)=6x25/49=150/49=3.0612...

Comment: I've posted a question below the answer of @Jon, could you answer it?

Comment: Yeah, I just did.

Comment: but why we are allowed to do that as the quantity of number we have is decreasing ?

Comment: The number of numbers one draws from is decreasing, yes, hence the probability to draw an odd number at a given time T becomes a mixture of proportions odd/(odd+even) present at time T, these proportions are random since they depend on the previous draws but... their average is exactly rigorously 25/49.

Comment: For example the probability to draw an odd number at the second draw is 24/48 if the first number drawn is odd, which happens with probability 25/49 and is 25/48 if the first number drawn is even, which happens with probability 24/49, thus the overall probability of an odd number at the second draw is (24/48)x(25/49)+(25/48)x(24/49)=25/49. Likewise for every draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6$ be $0$ or $1$ according to whether the $i$th choice is even or odd.  So $X=X_1+\cdots+X_6$.  You can now use linearity of expectation.

Comment: The probability that the $i$th choice is even or odd depends on what the $(i-1)$th choice was. In other words, $\mathrm{E}[X_2]$ is influenced by $X_1$.

Comment: @Eric S.  It doesn't matter.  Linearity of expectation holds for non-independent events.

Answer (score 1):

We consider the $7$ cases and determine how many odd balls are present in each case.

The $7$ cases are:

- $6$ even : $\dbinom{24}{6}$
- $5$ even, $1$ odd : $\dbinom{24}{5}\cdot 25$
- $4$ even, $2$ odd : $\dbinom{24}{4}\cdot \dbinom{25}{2}$
- $3$ even, $3$ odd : $\dbinom{24}{3}\cdot \dbinom{25}{3}$
- $2$ even, $4$ odd : $\dbinom{24}{2}\cdot \dbinom{25}{4}$
- $1$ even, $5$ odd : $24\cdot \dbinom{25}{5}$
- $6$ odd : $\dbinom{25}{6}$

Calculate all of these, multiply each by the corresponding number of odd balls, for example, $\dbinom{24}{4}\cdot \dbinom{25}{2}\times 2$, add them all up and divide by the total number of cases, $\dbinom{49}{6}$

Comment: My question was about an example without replacing them i.e. the quantity of those number is decreasing thus i think the answer could be different or is it the same?

Comment: no its the same - try the version with replacement and you get a different answer; @mkropkowski